# How to ensure computer is power on always?

Tags: bios, shutdown, power-management

I would like to have my computer to turn on in all cases wall socket electricity is on. I know there is a BIOS setting for it,

[image]

but I am not sure I can rely on this: battery can discharge or induction can happen so that BIOS set to factory default.

Can I configure it in hardware, may be some jumpers or short circuit power on switch?

---

I want to do the same as can be done with `BIOS` on screenshot, but without relying on `BIOS`.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Specifically, the first sentence of your question, is not written in a clear concise manner.  You should [edit] your question to resolve that issue.

Comment: Do you mean to say that you do not want to press the Power on button? Whenever PSU senses Mains input, it should just turn on the PC, i.e. as soon as you switch on the Mains, PC should just start? Short circuiting Power On button might help only once just to start it but most Firmwares by default when sense long pressed Power On for 3 – 4 seconds will shut down the PC instantly and then it will not restart unless you release  the button and then separately press it again.

Comment: Unless you're running from read-only media (e.g., booting from a DVD), this likely will cause problems if you *shut down by cutting power*. Otherwise, how would you ever shut the PC?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik for example, with `poweroff` command

Comment: @Dims, that won't work, according to your request: "I would like to have my computer to turn on in all cases wall socket electricity is on." It can't be both *off* and *on* at the same time (unless it's a quantum computer).

Comment: You can only control for the factors you can control for. You cannot control for everything. You need to address the circumstances you CAN deal with to begin with, and then develop mitigations for the circumstances that are harder to control for. And then you need to accept some problems may be beyond your control. If there were jumpers on this main board they'd be documented and you'd be able to follow that document. But unless this main board is a decade or more older, I doubt it has jumpers.

Comment: @music2myear so, modern motherboards don't contain means to be reliably power on?

Comment: They contain means to power on when the criteria for powering on are met. Your contention is moot. You clearly have a scenario that is outside the norm. You will need to find the special tools to handle that scenario, or adjust your expectations.

Comment: So, my criteria are "always", how to power on when they are met?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik why are you trying to make clear question fuzzy? What is guiding you!? Incredible!